# How do I play a .wav file in Windows?

Tags: python, windows, audio, wav

I tried playing .wav files in Windows using the following Python code:

```
import wave
w = wave.open('D:/Music/Chris Stapleton - Nobody to Blame.wav', 'r')
for i in range(w.getnframes()):
    frame = w.readframes(i)
    print(frame)
```

Code output:

```
7\xfd\xfaD\xf8\xbd\xfb\xdb\xf96\xfd\xd0\xfb\xd7\xfe\xd7\xfc\x90\xffN\xfd\xc9\xff0\xfeR\x002\xff\xb3\x00\x88\xffR\x00P\xff\xa0\xff+\xff \xff\x02\xff\x80\xfeH\xfeS\xfd6\xfd\xf0\xfbY\xfc\xf2\xfa\xe6\xfb\x8b\xfa)\xfc\xd5\xfa\xf4\xfc\xa8\xfb\'\xfd \xfc\x96\xfc\xe7\xfb[\xfc\xd7\xfbt\xfc\x03\xfc\xd7\xfbo\xfbl\xfa\xfb\xf9\xfc\xf8\x7f\xf8N\xf8\xca\xf7\xc7\xf8W\xf8%\xfa\xf1\xf9\x07\xfc\x1e\xfc\x03\xfe~\xfe\x03\xff\x02\x00\xba\xfe\x14\x00c\xfe\xe8\xff1\xfe\xde\xff(\xfd\xdf\xfe\xc1\xfbZ\xfd\xf5\xfag\xfc~\xfa\xca\xfb\x84\xfa\xb4\xfbl\xfb\x93\xfcS\xfcz\xfd\xcd\xfc\x06\xfeY\xfd\xb7\xfe\xa6\xfd\x18\xff\x87\xfd\x0e\xffz\xfd,\xff6\xfd\xf6\xfe\xcb\xfcn\xfe\x14\xfd\x83\xfeN\xfdl\xfeq\xfc!\xfd\xae\xfb\xd1\xfb\x18\xfc\x84\xfb\x02\xfd\xc8\xfb\xb0\xfd\x0b\xfc\xe0\xfd\xe7\xfb\x0c\xfe\xe5\xfb\x1b\xff\x17\xfdT\x00\x9c\xfe\x98\x00\'\xff\xf3\x00\xb2\xff\xeb\x01\xb4\x00\x06\x02\xaa\x00>\x01x\xff\xe8\x00\x7f\xfe\xe5\x00\xf7\xfd\xc1\x00\x8f\xfd\x15\x01\xcf\xfd\x86\x02\x88\xff\x1f\x05\xd0\x02\xfb\x07\x8d\x06\xe3\tl\t\xa2\n\x0e\x0b\x1f\n\x13\x0b\xf9\x07\x15\t\x95\x05\x95\x06\x01\x05\xaf\x05\xd9\x05\x1b\x06\xca\x06\xa5\x06C\x08\xdb\x07\x02\x0b\xa5\n\x0f\x0e\xfc\r\xc0\x0f\x05\x10\xb7\x0fP\x10\xf1\x0e\xc4\x0f\xf6\r\xdb\x0e\x80\x0cR\r\xd6\n_\x0b\xb5\t\xc6\tR\t\xee\x08\x86\t\xb4\x08\x00\n\xc0\x08T\n\xca\x08\x89\n\xd0\x08\xec\n\xf5\x08j\x0bD\t\xe5\x0b\xb7\tp\x0c5\n\xee\x0c\x7f\n\x0e\rS\n\xb4\x0c\xa7\t\t\x0c\xa1\x08M\x0b`\x07\xb8\n1\x06\xaa\n\xad\x056\x0b\xea\x05\xb3\x0b8\x06\xd7\x0bk\x06\x1c\x0c\xed\x068\x0cU\x07s\x0b\xe6\x06I\n\x01\x06F\t!\x05\xf2\x07\xda\x03^\x06:\x02]\x05\x1c\x01\xd4\x04\x9c\x00V\x04W\x00\x87\x04\xd8\x00\x97\x05R\x02\xf5\x057\x03\xac\x04}\x02\x05\x03U\x01\xe4\x01\x92\x00U\x00B\xff;\xfeK\xfd\xcd\xfc\xdd\xfb4\xfc7\xfb\xe1\xfb\xdd\xfa\xdf\xfb\xba\xfa\x10\xfc\xb7\xfa_\xfc\xf8\xfa%\xfd\xd1\xfb\xd1\xfd\x8f\xfc\x97\xfdw\xfc\x08\xfd*\xfc\x98\xfc\x14\xfc\xea\xfb\xbc\xfbI\xfb?\xfb\xd8\xfa\xb3\xfa\xcf\xf9e\xf9S\xf8w\xf7H\xf7\xc9\xf5\x9b\xf6p\xf4\x02\xf6R\xf3\x82\xf5\xa8\xf2\xe9\xf4I\xf2\x82\xf4g\xf2\xe0\xf4\x84\xf3z\xf5\x02\xf5\xb6\xf5\xff\xf5\xdd\xf5\x91\xf6\xcd\xf5\x84\xf6I\xf5\x92\xf56\xf5\xc2\xf4\xf3\xf5\xb8\xf4\x82\xf6\x97\xf4\xc2\xf6f\xf4\xc8\xf7v\xf5\xd8\xf9\r\xf8"\xfc5\xfb\xd0\xfd\xe3\xfd%\xfe+\xff\xb9\xfc\x84\xfe\x13\xfaY\xfc\x83\xf7\xe0\xf9\x03\xf66\xf8b\xf5\\\xf70\xf5\x04\xf7\xf0\xf5\xd1\xf7\xcd\xf7\x0b\xfa\x8b\xf9f\xfc.\xfa\xdd\xfd\xca\xf9x\xfe\x9b\xf87\xfe,\xf7\x82\xfd\x1d\xf6\xf6\xfc\x1d\xf56\xfc4\xf4D\xfb7\xf4\x00\xfb\xb7\xf4\x01\xfb\xe3\xf4\x94\xfa\x86\xf5\xa5\xfa\xdf\xf6q\xfb\xe0\xf7\xf4\xfb\xfc\xf8\xb2\xfc!\xfb\x9a\xfe<\xfd\x98\x00`\xfe\x9e\x01)\xff"\x02\xca\xffe\x02\x1a\x00@\x02\x90\x00\x0c\x02;\x01\xeb\x01\xbb\x01\xb3\x01t\x02\xd9\x01\xc1\x03\xca\x02\xcc\x04\xc6\x03\xea\x04\x14\x04\xcf\x04Z\x04\r\x05\x0e\x05\xfa\x04c\x05l\x04\x1d\x05\x0f\x04\xdf\x04\xb1\x03p\x044\x03\xcc\x03\xf9\x03i\x04e\x06\xb1\x06\xe0\x08"\t\x90\n\xdf\n\xa0\x0b\x03\x0c\xce\x0bO\x0cR\x0b\xec\x0b\xc4\nY\x0b\xb7\t>\n\xed\x07h\x08c\x06\xb3\x06\xa3\x05\xb9\x05F\x05+\x05\x16\x05\xc7\x04\x0c\x05{\x04\xe2\x04\x0c\x04v\x04o\x03\xf0\x03\xe8\x02{\x03\x9f\x028\x03\xa9\x02!\x03\x05\x03\xe1\x02H\x03I\x02\x15\x03\xa9\x01\x9f\x02*\x01\xe6\x01\x81\x00\x8f\x00\xcf\xff\xea\xfe~\xff\x8b\xfdV\xffY\xfc\x01\xff@\xfb\x99\xfe\x83\xfaS\xfe[\xfaw\xfe\x0c\xfb\xd8\xfe:\xfc\xa3\xfe\xb7\xfc\xea\xfdi\xfcp\xfd\x03\xfc\xe3\xfc\'\xfb\x1e\xfc\xb9\xf9\x13\xfc\xd5\xf8x\xfc~\xf8U\xfc\x06\xf8\x83\xfcW\xf8\xff\xfdh\xfa\xf3\xfff\xfd\x13\x01\xd0\xff\xba\x00\xbe\x00(\xffM\x00\xfb\xfc\xec\xfe*\xfaz\xfcV\xf7\xb7\xf99\xf6q\xf8\xd6\xf6\xc5\xf8\x15\xf8\xd3\xf9#\xfa\xe1\xfb!\xfc\x0f\xfeA\xfc\x95\xfe{\xfb^\xfeC\xfb\xc7\xfe\x9a\xfa\xb8\xfeI\xf9\xcf\xfdT\xf8\x02\xfde\xf7\x02\xfcp\xf6\xb4\xfaG\xf6\xee\xf9b\xf6L\xf91\xf6S\xf8.\xf6\xa2\xf7*\xf64\xf7$\xf6\xfe\xf6\xe9\xf6\xcd\xf7\x0c\xf8C\xf9\x9a\xf8A\xfa\xbc\xf8\xbe\xfa\xa2\xf8\xd6\xfa\x8c\xf8\xb9\xfaL\xf9/\xfb\x86\xfa\xe5\xfb(\xfb\xdf\xfb\xcb\xfb\xe1\xfb{\xfd\x1a\xfd\xd4\xff\'\xff\xd7\x01\x13\x01\xa2\x02\xff\x01\xf5\x01\x8c\x01\x12\x01\xe5\x00\x0e\x01\x12\x01\xdd\x00\xef\x00\x92\xff\x95\xffn\xfeY\xfe\xa3\xfej\xfe\x9e\xff=\xff\xcf\x00Y\x00]\x02\xdf\x01\x87\x03\x0f\x03\x17\x03\xb4\x02g\x01\x1b\x01\xd5\xff\xa8\xff\xcd\xfe\xcd\xfe\xee\xfd\x1f\xfe\x11\xfdz\xfd\x17\xfc\xb4\xfc\xf1\xfa\xa6\xfba\xfa\x17\xfb(\xfb\xc4\xfbu\xfc\xd3\xfc\x0b\xfd \xfd+\xfd\x0f\xfdw\xfdP\xfd\xb5\xfd\xb7\xfd\xee\xfdT\xfej\xfeT\xff\xb4\xfe\x19\x00\xc5\xfeq\x00.\xff\xc5\x00_\xff|\x00\xe2\xfe)\xff\xed\xfe!\xfe\xf8\xff\x1b\xfe\xcd\x00!\xfe\x1e\x01\x0b\xfe\x90\x01\x99\xfe,\x02\xc0\xff\xd6\x022\x01u\x03\xad\x02\x99\x03\x83\x03h\x03\x93\x03l\x03\\\x03\x95\x03\xf1\x02\xe4\x03p\x02\xd3\x04z\x02|\x06c\x03q\x08\xf9\x04@\n\xe0\x06\x0e\x0c%\tE\x0e\n\x0c\xe1\x0fs\x0e*\x0f\x82\x0e\xba\x0c\xa5\x0ck\n\x9d\n\x81\x08\xaf\x08\xfb\x06\xf6\x06\x85\x06D\x06\xec\x06u\x06\xb2\x07\x19\x07\xc8\x08F\x08o\tM\t\x17\t\x86\t"\x08H\t\xa1\x06\x92\x08\xee\x04\x9f\x07\x0f\x04S\x07\xa4\x038\x07\xe2\x02u\x06\x7f\x02\xb8\x05\x97\x02,\x05c\x02*\x04\x86\x02x\x03\x84\x03\xb8\x03j\x04\x14\x04\xf8\x04_\x04\xa8\x05\xff\x04T\x06\xb4\x05\xd9\x06Q\x06\xf4\x06r\x06N\x06\x99\x05\xc1\x05\x9b\x04\xe4\x05%\x04\xe9\x05{\x03"\x06\xfe\x02\x89\x07\xbd\x03\x03\t\xb4\x047\t\xa3\x04\xad\x08\x0e\x04\xca\x07E\x03*\x06\xdc\x018\x04F\x00\xd1\x02O\xff\xfd\x01\xe5\xfe*\x01i\xfeO\x00\xdf\xfd\\\x006\xfe\xad\x01\xb4\xff\x05\x03\x12\x01@\x03D\x01\x8b\x02\x89\x00a\x01\\\xff\xf4\xff\xf8\xfdL\xfeu\xfcx\xfc\xe4\xfa\xca\xfa\x9d\xf9g\xf9\xaf\xf8\x1d\xf8\xc0\xf7W\xf7)\xf7l\xf7K\xf7}\xf7F\xf7\t\xf7\xa2\xf6\xb8\xf6\x1f\xf6\xab\xf6\x04\xf6\x91\xf6%\xf6\xac\xf6\xc2\xf6\xd1\xf6\x8d\xf7i\xf6\xcf\xf7\xd9\xf5\xc9\xf7\xb8\xf5\xed\xf7\x88\xf5\xa0\xf7\xb4\xf4G\xf6\xd4\xf3\x97\xf4\xfc\xf3\xe2\xf3-\xf5W\xf4d\xf6\x16\xf5O\xf7\xed\xf5[\xf8E\xf7D\xf9\xbe\xf8\x8f\xf9\xba\xf9~\xf9D\xfa\\\xf9q\xfa!\xf91\xfa\xf5\xf8\xb4\xf9\x1f\xf9S\xf9\xed\xf9y\xf9O\xfbH\xfa\x96\xfcB\xfb\xb3\xfdt\xfcu\xff\x99\xfeu\x011\x01D\x02\xc8\x02\xa8\x01\x04\x03.\x00=\x02\xf7\xfd|\x00\xa3\xfbb\xfeR\xfa\x1d\xfd8\xfa\xef\xfc\xcf\xfaY\xfd\xef\xfbJ\xfe\x81\xfd\xcb\xff\x04\xffi\x01\xed\xff\x97\x02\xeb\xff\x04\x03\x0e\xff\xae\x025\xfe`\x028\xfe\xe1\x02K\xfeE\x03h\xfdk\x02\xb5\xfcu\x01F\xfd\x82\x01\xce\xfdY\x01\xa5\xfdn\x00\x1e\xfe*\x00^\xff\xd6\x00o\x00\x9a\x01\x98\x01\xb0\x02\x0b\x036\x04\x13\x04r\x05\xbc\x04\\\x06W\x05$\x07\xb4\x05\x87\x07I\x06\xf3\x07\xac\x07\x07\t\x84\ts\n\x97\x0b\xfb\x0b\xe0\r\xa8\r\xb1\x0f\xeb\x0e\x9f\x10a\x0f\xea\x10Q\x0f\x99\x10\xce\x0e\xb4\x0f\xde\r\x87\x0e\xcd\x0c?\r\xc2\x0b5\x0c\x02\x0b\xcd\x0b\xda\n\xda\x0b\x0e\x0bE\x0c}\x0bI\r`\x0c?\x0e\x17\r\x08\x0e\x7f\x0c\x88\x0c\x98\nl\n8\x08N\x08\x03\x06\x8d\x06T\x04,\x052\x03\t\x04p\x02;\x03\r\x02\xa3\x02\xcc\x01\xe9\x016\x01B\x01\x83\x00\x13\x01+\x008\x01\x19\x00\x7f\x01;\x00\xc7\x01\x8f\x00\xb5\x01\xc1\x00\x87\x01\x07\x01\xeb\x01\xfa\x01R\x02\xe2\x02\x9f\x01y\x02\x1e\x00\xf2\x00\xd6\xfeQ\xff<\xfe#\xfen\xfe\xa7\xfd\x02\xff\x8e\xfdJ\xffW\xfd\x93\xffi\xfdA\x00"\xfe\xa6\x00\xc3\xfec\x00\xda\xfe\xbe\xff\x88\xfe\x81\xfey\xfd\xba\xfc\xaf\xfb\x1b\xfb\xd7\xf9\xe3\xf9?\xf8\x80\xf9d\xf7}\xfa\xe8\xf7\xd5\xfb\xed\xf8\x8d\xfc\x90\xf9\xa5\xfd\xcd\xfa\x8a\xff\x0f\xfd\xe4\x00\xf7\xfe\xe9\x00\xa2\xff\x94\xff\xf1\xfe\xca\xfc\xb6\xfcz\xf9\xd4\xf9%\xf7\xd2\xf7\x1a\xf6\x03\xf7\xea\xf5\x00\xf7O\xf6\x97\xf7\xed\xf6w\xf8h\xf7G\xf9\x9f\xf7\xf1\xf9|\xf7f\xfa\x04\xf7\x9f\xfaW\xf6\xb0\xfa\xb6\xf5\xc9\xfaK\xf5\xfc\xfa\xd6\xf4\xf3\xfap\xf4\xaf\xfa\xc1\xf4\xd3\xfal\xf5\x0f\xfb\xb1\xf5\xb4\xfa\x82\xf6\xca\xfa{\xf8\x12\xfc\x0b\xfa\x12\xfd\xb4\xfaK\xfd\xc8\xfb\x14\xfe\x10\xfd6\xff\x84\xfd\x9f\xff\xc2\xfd\xe0\xffX\xfev\x00\xbe\xfe\xd2\x00\x1b\xff\x1e\x01\x13\x00\xeb\x01\x95\x01\x16\x03K\x03Q\x04\xe1\x04V\x05\x16\x06\xf6\x05\xda\x065\x06\xb0\x06\xad\x05k\x05;\x04\x19\x04\xf6\x029\x03S\x02\xeb\x01\\\x01\x81\x00L\x00z\x00\x85\x00\xa7\x01\xce\x01\xc0\x02\xe3\x02\x84\x03{\x03\xf6\x03\x97\x03\x7f\x03\xb9\x02\xff\x01\xde\x00J\x00\xeb\xfe)\xff\xaf\xfd\x83\xfe\x19\xfd\xe7\xfd\xbc\xfcx\xfd\xb1\xfce\xfd\x02\xfdX\xfd>\xfdq\xfd~\xfd\x16\xfe\'\xfe\xae\xfe\xa6\xfe\xcc\xfe\xa8\xfeJ\xff#\xff\\\x00X\x001\x01y\x01\xdc\x01\x85\x02\x8c\x02\x90\x03\x8c\x02\xc8\x03\x02\x02;\x03\xd1\x01\xca\x02\xee\x01y\x02|\x02x\x02F\x04\xac\x03\xb6\x06\x9e\x05\x97\x08 \x07\'\ni\x08\xb4\x0b\xc3\ti\x0cW\n\x16\x0c\xe8\td\x0b\x13\tP\n\xc9\x07\xa0\x08\xdd\x05\x00\x07\x06\x04H\x06\x18\x03y\x06\x13\x03&\x07\x9f\x03B\x08\xbc\x04\xde\tz\x06|\x0bW\x08|\x0c\xa9\t\xe5\x0cr\n\xac\x0c\x9f\n\x12\x0bc\t\t\x08\xa6\x06*\x05\xfd\x03\xf9\x03\xe9\x02\x13\x04\x12\x03C\x04G\x03t\x04n\x03^\x05F\x04\xd2\x06\xb4\x05\x86\x07\x7f\x06\xd5\x06\x02\x06\xac\x05&\x05\x0e\x05\xe8\x04h\x04\xb0\x04\xe5\x02\x91\x03Q\x01:\x02\xaa\x00\x9a\x01Z\x00%\x01\x06\x00\x86\x00\x8c\x00\xa6\x00\xe1\x01\x8c\x01\xca\x02\x0f\x02\x06\x03\xf8\x01C\x03\xf8\x01\x9a\x03)\x02\x89\x03\x0f\x02\xd7\x02q\x01\x06\x02\xcd\x00\xc8\x01\xd1\x00\xc9\x01\x1b\x01~\x01\x02\x01\xae\x018\x01&\x03|\x02\x11\x05\xf3\x03X\x06\x8f\x04\xbb\x06/\x04/\x06\xee\x02\xe9\x04#\x01\x84\x03r\xff\x1c\x02\xf8\xfdO\x00T\xfc_\xfe\xb0\xfa4\xfd\xd1\xf9\x12\xfd\xeb\xf9&\xfd(\xfa\xda\xfc\xf2\xf9\x90\xfc\xab\xf9\x01\xfc\r\xf9\x07\xfa\x01\xf7\x0e\xf7\x06\xf4\xdb\xf4\xed\xf1\xb1\xf3\xff\xf0\xb8\xf2n\xf0\x13\xf2X\xf0\x1d\xf2\t\xf1S\xf2\xeb\xf1P\xf2\x83\xf2b\xf2\x08\xf3\xe4\xf2\xd1\xf3\xeb\xf3\x03\xf5>\xf5y\xf6{\xf6\xdc\xf7r\xf7\x02\xf9-\xf8\xf8\xf9X\xf8d\xfa\x8c\xf7\xce\xf9`\xf6\xb8\xf8\xb3\xf5\t\xf86\xf5\x80\xf7\xb0\xf4\xef\xf6Y\xf5\x97\xf7\x98\xf7\xe0\xf9\xc9\xf9!\xfc\xff\xfaY\xfd\xe7\xfb\'\xfe\xa3\xfc\xa8\xfe\x84\xfc7\xfeG\xfb\x9c\xfcO\xf9K\xfai\xf7&\xf8\xe9\xf5\x88\xf6\x87\xf4 \xf5\xec\xf3\x8c\xf4\x03\xf5\xb0\xf5\xc0\xf6z\xf7\xf9\xf7\xbe\xf8\x90\xf9a\xfa\xeb\xfb\xd1\xfc\xa4\xfd\xad\xfe\xf7\xfd*\xff\x1b\xfd\x7f\xfe\x15\xfb\xb3\xfc\x8e\xf8j\xfa\x08\xf7\x1d\xf9\xfe\xf6L\xf9a\xf7\xeb\xf9}\xf7B\xfa<\xf88\xfb]\xfa\x8f\xfd\x7f\xfc\xf0\xff\x1a\xfd\xe0\x00\xde\xfc\x0e\x01\xc9\xfcw\x01{\xfc\xb3\x01\xd8\xfb\x98\x01\x84\xfb\xb3\x01\x9a\xfb\x0f\x02\xef\xfbx\x02\xc3\xfc/\x03L\xfel\x04d\x00\x17\x06\x9e\x02\xcb\x07\x86\x04\x14\t4\x06\x0c\n\xdb\x07\xf3\n\xd0\x084\x0b\x8d\x08Y\n\xe4\x07E\t\xba\x07\xea\x08\xab\x07\xe3\x08U\x07\xb1\x08y\x07\xf1\x08\x91\x08\xfe\t\xd2\t\xf9\n\xc1\n`\x0b\xcb\x0b\xb6\x0b\x99\x0c\xc6\x0b\x15\x0c\x9c\nR\n]\x08\x7f\x08D\x064\x07\xe8\x048\x06\x03\x04z\x05p\x03G\x05l\x03\x8c\x05\xe0\x03\xb2\x05.\x04\x91\x05 \x04V\x05\xdf\x03t\x04\xdc\x02r\x02\xa2\x00(\x00\x19\xfey\xfe9\xfcE\xfd\xfd\xfao\xfcR\xfa\xdf\xfb\x1f\xfa\x19\xfb\xdd\xf94\xfa\x91\xf9\xe0\xf9\xc9\xf91\xfa\x85\xfa\xd2\xfan\xfb'
b'\x97\xfb^\xfc@\xfc \xfd\xac\xfc\x96\xfd\xf1\xfc\xd9\xfd\xd3\xfc\xb0\xfd\xf1\xfb\xb8\xfcO\xfa\xf6\xfat\xf8\xff\xf8\x1c\xf7\xa2\xf7\xa6\xf6H\xf7\x03\xf7\xe3\xf7b\xf8\x95\xf9\xa6\xfa!\xfc\xa2\xfc1\xfe\x97\xfd\xed\xfe9\xfe\x06\xff\xbe\xfe\xc7\xfe\x11\xfe<\xfd\xc5\xfb$\xfa\xee\xf8\xbc\xf6z\xf6\n\xf4i\xf4\x00\xf2\xdd\xf2\xaa\xf0v\xf2\x8e\xf0\x01\xf3a\xf1\xaf\xf3C\xf2\xc7\xf4}\xf3\xd4\xf6\xa4\xf5\xb4\xf8\xa4\xf71\xf9J\xf8\xc1\xf8\x12\xf8\xa9\xf7A\xf7T\xf5<\xf5\xae\xf2\xe4\xf2\x96\xf1\x16\xf2\x0b\xf2\xd0\xf2\xf9\xf2\xfa\xf3y\xf4\xab\xf5\x01\xf7Y\xf8\xe3\xf9]\xfb\xf0\xfb\x8b\xfd\xab\xfcn\xfe\xa8\xfc\xa0\xfe\xa7\xfc\xe3\xfes\xfc\xfe\xfe\x9e\xfbx\xfe\xbb\xfa\xe3\xfds\xfa\xe5\xfd\x81\xfa/\xfe\xc6\xfa\x9a\xfe\xb0\xfb\x94\xff\x1d\xfd\xf6\x00p\xfe\x17\x02\x7f\xff\xc5\x02\x92\x00M\x03\xad\x01\xc9\x03>\x02\xc2\x03\xe2\x01\xf3\x02I\x01#\x02$\x01\x0f\x02<\x01o\x02\xa7\x017\x03\xd7\x02\xb1\x04S\x04;\x06\xba\x05\\\x07\x7f\x07\x8d\x08@\t\x83\t\t\nj\t\xf7\tz\x08f\t(\x07y\x08\xa8\x05\xc4\x07\x92\x04X\x07\xed\x03\xc4\x06@\x03y\x06\xfd\x02\xd3\x06r\x03B\x07\xfe\x03\x8f\x07Z\x04q\x07.\x04I\x06\xd8\x02\xde\x04&\x017\x042\x00\xa1\x03k\xff\xc5\x02\x94\xfea\x02x\xfe,\x02\xcd\xfe\xca\x01&\xff7\x02]\x00\xdb\x03\xbc\x02\xf8\x05r\x058\x08\x1b\x08\x8c\n\xa3\n\x99\x0c\xb1\x0c\x14\x0e\xfc\r\xd9\x0ej\x0e\xf7\x0e\x11\x0ew\x0e\x11\r\x1f\rQ\x0b6\x0b=\t\xb5\t\xdc\x07$\t\xb7\x07\x98\t\xcb\x08\xff\n\xd3\n\x96\x0c\xce\x0c\x9d\r\xca\r<\x0e\xe2\r\x8f\x0eI\r\x11\x0e\xaf\x0bm\x0c\xfa\x08\xf0\t\xb1\x05\\\x07\xb3\x028\x05\x82\x00X\x03\xd4\xfe\xc9\x01\x8c\xfd-\x01$\xfd\xc0\x01\xca\xfdI\x03F\xff\x80\x05c\x01\xbe\x07\x8b\x03K\t\x13\x05\xa9\t\x84\x05m\x08w\x04\xe3\x05-\x02\xf7\x02\x88\xff:\x00\x1b\xfdk\xfe\xa7\xfbd\xfe\x07\xfc\xa5\xff\xb7\xfd(\x01\xac\xff\xca\x02\xbf\x01;\x04\x9d\x03\xfb\x04\xbd\x04?\x05V\x05\xe6\x04K\x05\x97\x03F\x04\x0c\x02\x04\x03\xdc\x00"\x02\xd0\xffj\x01:\xff.\x01P\xff\x9e\x01\x8b\xff%\x02\x01\x00\xc7\x02\x15\x01\xd0\x03\\\x02\xc5\x04[\x03%\x05\xca\x03\xb7\x04\x85\x03u\x03\x1b\x03\x1c\x02\xea\x029\x01m\x02c\x00\x91\x01\x87\xff\xaa\x00\xe5\xfe\xa7\xffH\xfe\x06\xff\x00\xfeg\xff\x88\xfe\x1f\x00!\xffn\x00\x15\xff\x91\x00\xb7\xfee\x00\xfd\xfdl\xff\x81\xfc\x1f\xfe\xd0\xfa7\xfd\xad\xf9n\xfc\xd7\xf8E\xfb\xce\xf7D\xfa\x16\xf7I\xfa\x7f\xf7\xf1\xfa\x98\xf8H\xfbT\xf9e\xfb\xb4\xf9\xb8\xfb\x17\xfa\x13\xfcL\xfa>\xfc*\xfa\xf2\xfb\x8c\xf9\xd7\xfa=\xf8u\xf9\xe0\xf6\x94\xf8R\xf6\x17\xf8t\xf6\xc6\xf7\xfc\xf6\xb9\xf7\xe5\xf7\x05\xf8#\xf9\x1d\xf9\x10\xfb\x18\xfb\xab\xfd\xd1\xfc\xbe\xff\x8b\xfd\x82\x00\xbc\xfdv\x00\x94\xfd\xd5\xff\xc5\xfcy\xfeI\xfb\x86\xfcQ\xf9\\\xfa\x88\xf7\xc6\xf8\xb5\xf6\x8c\xf8\xfa\xf6\xb0\xf9x\xf8\x1a\xfc\x07\xfbZ\xffC\xfd\xd0\x01\x86\xfe\xc0\x02\t\x00r\x03\xe5\x014\x04h\x02\x9a\x03\xf0\x00A\x01V\xfe&\xfe\x8d\xfb;\xfbi\xf98\xf9M\xf8T\xf8\xe8\xf7\x1a\xf8\x0b\xf8F\xf8\n\xf9/\xf9]\xfbb\xfb\xb6\xfe\xa4\xfe\x81\x01p\x01\xba\x02\xc4\x02\x15\x03N\x03\xa4\x02\x11\x03m\x00\t\x01\x80\xfdG\xfe1\xfc%\xfd\x82\xfc\xaf\xfdP\xfd\xc6\xfe\x19\xff\xe5\x00j\x02\x94\x04\r\x06\x8d\x08\xa6\x08e\x0b-\n\r\r\'\x0b\n\x0e\xa6\x0bs\x0e_\x0b\n\x0eT\n\xe3\x0c\x16\t\x9f\x0bP\x08\xfa\n6\x08)\x0bQ\x08\xb0\x0b\x16\x08\xed\x0b\xa5\x07\xe0\x0b\x8f\x07\xf8\x0b\x0e\x08X\x0c\xe0\x08\xb8\x0cl\t\x8d\x0c\x0b\tX\x0b\xf2\x07}\t\x1e\x07 \x08\xba\x06\x83\x07\x1e\x06\xf9\x06y\x05\x96\x06o\x05\xd3\x06\xc7\x05N\x07Q\x06\xb7\x07x\x07s\x08\xe6\x085\t\x99\t\x13\t\x8c\t \x08\x82\t9\x07\x8f\t\x85\x06\xee\x08L\x05V\x07M\x03\xbe\x05\x84\x01\xe8\x04\xb0\x00-\x04"\x00H\x03\x83\xff\x01\x03\x82\xff\x07\x03\xb7\xff]\x02\x13\xff\x8f\x01"\xfe5\x01\x8c\xfdZ\x00w\xfcu\xfe{\xfa7\xfci\xf8@\xfa\xf0\xf6\x01\xf9\x82\xf6\xa9\xf8;\xf7\xc5\xf8\x8c\xf88\xf9/\xfa_\xfaZ\xfc\x00\xfc\xac\xfey\xfdp\x00r\xfeF\x01\xce\xfe"\x01\x9f\xfe>\x00\xbc\xfd\xa4\xfe\xba\xfb#\xfc\xf8\xf8B\xf9[\xf6\xf4\xf6Z\xf4\x98\xf5\x8f\xf3\x96\xf5Q\xf4\x04\xf7\x90\xf5\x9b\xf8f\xf6X\xf9W\xf7\xc9\xf9x\xf8,\xfa\xbf\xf8\xb1\xf9\xa3\xf7\x05\xf8Q\xf5o\xf5\x04\xf2,\xf2b\xee\xc3\xee\x86\xeb-\xec\x18\xea\xf0\xea\xd4\xe9\xbc\xea`\xea=\xeb\x02\xec\xd0\xec\xc0\xee\x8d\xef\xc5\xf1\xaf\xf2c\xf4\x82\xf5K\xf6\xa9\xf7\x1a\xf7\xb0\xf8\xb1\xf6k\xf8;\xf5\x08\xf7X\xf33\xf5p\xf2h\xf4*\xf3a\xf5\x9b\xf4;\xf7m\xf6\x9b\xf9\x1c\xf9\xea\xfc\xe5\xfbO\x00\xc2\xfd\xa9\x02\xb9\xfe\xee\x03\xfc\xfeF\x04\xd4\xfe\x02\x04\x8e\xfe\x84\x03\xba\xfdt\x02\x95\xfc.\x013\xfc\xdb\x00\x12\xfc\x01\x01`\xfb\xbf\x00\x1d\xfb\xf9\x00\xcb\xfb\x05\x02\xb0\xfc\x03\x03\xf5\xfd\x02\x04\x8c\xff\xf6\x04o\x00\xf1\x04\xb4\x005\x041\x01\xc8\x03\xc0\x01\xa9\x03\xe2\x01g\x03g\x01\xc9\x02\xbf\x00#\x02\xf7\x00]\x02\xd0\x01\x1e\x03\x14\x02\x1c\x03X\x02\xef\x02\xa6\x03\xab\x03\xf7\x04X\x04r\x05.\x04\xdc\x05\xfd\x03j\x06\x06\x04\x9a\x06\xce\x03\x86\x06z\x03\x8e\x06p\x03\xdb\x06\xdc\x03\x7f\x07\xc4\x04Z\x08\xf4\x05[\t?\x07{\n\x81\x08z\x0bf\t-\x0c\xbf\t\x81\x0c\x89\t,\x0c\x9c\x08\x13\x0b\x05\x07\xb4\tf\x05\xbb\x08\x87\x04B\x08\x85\x04\xaf\x07\xb7\x04\x11\x07\t\x05v\x07\\\x06\xd4\x08{\x08\xcb\t\xe1\t\x0c\n1\nf\nB\n\xe2\n:\n\xc5\n\x8b\t\x98\t\xee\x07\x9d\x07\xc5\x05j\x05\xb4\x03\x04\x03\xb3\x01\xc3\x00\xf4\xffF\x00\xe8\xff\xd0\x01\xad\x01I\x03\x17\x03\x11\x04\x8b\x03\x8b\x05\x88\x04\x82\x07\xfb\x05X\x08d\x06i\x07-\x05\x0f\x05\xa6\x02\x1a\x02\x8d\xfff\xff\xa5\xfcQ\xfd=\xfa\\\xfc\xdc\xf8\xcb\xfc\xd6\xf8\xc1\xfdl\xf9\n\xff}\xfa_\x01\xcd\xfc\xe7\x03x\xffR\x05\x19\x01\t\x06\xfd\x01\xf3\x05\xf8\x01\xf4\x03\xeb\xff\x02\x01\xd7\xfc \xff\xda\xfaA\xfe\x04\xfa\xaf\xfd\xb6\xf9\xf7\xfd\x86\xfa\x91\xff\xe1\xfc\xc9\x01\xf7\xff\x96\x03\x9c\x02\x9d\x04M\x04I\x05]\x05\xc8\x05\xec\x05r\x05`\x05\x16\x04\xa2\x03\xb9\x02\xe3\x01\x02\x02\xf2\x00\x1c\x01\x17\x00F\xff\x96\xfeG\xfd(\xfd\x1a\xfc\x9f\xfce\xfbx\xfc\xb0\xfa\x13\xfc\x89\xfa\xec\xfb\x12\xfb)\xfcD\xfb\xde\xfb\xc7\xfa\xd7\xfa}\xfa\x1b\xfa\x94\xfa\xed\xf9=\xfa\x82\xf9|\xf9\xcf\xf8%\xf9\x93\xf8S\xf9\xd1\xf8\xb1\xf9&\xf9s\xfa\xbf\xf9\x9b\xfb\x9e\xfa\x9a\xfc<\xfbU\xfd\x82\xfb*\xfe\xd3\xfb\x08\xff\'\xfc\x90\xff(\xfc\xab\xff\xd1\xfb\x8b\xffg\xfb]\xff\'\xfb*\xff\x1f\xfb\x1e\xffu\xfb\x88\xff^\xfc*\x00z\xfdl\x00\x12\xfeq\x001\xfe\x9b\x008\xfeb\x00\xb1\xfd\'\xff!\xfcQ\xfd\x18\xfa\xaa\xfb\x83\xf8j\xfa\xad\xf7p\xf9q\xf7\xd9\xf8\xd5\xf7\xe5\xf8\xf3\xf8\x85\xf9\x91\xfa\x83\xfaV\xfc\xaf\xfb\xff\xfd\xcb\xfcN\xff\x0e\xfe\x8b\x00\xc0\xff\x17\x02\xc6\x00\xf3\x02\xea\xff\xfd\x01"\xfe1\x00\x94\xfc\xae\xfe\xb7\xfa\xdd\xfc\xdf\xf8\x04\xfb\x91\xf8\xa1\xfa\x8f\xf9w\xfb\x96\xfaR\xfc\xde\xfb{\xfd\xdc\xfdr\xff\xc2\xffm\x01\x8d\x00]\x02\xde\xff\xcf\x01\xe5\xfd\xdc\xffS\xfb&\xfd6\xf9\xb8\xfa`\xf8v\xf9\xa6\xf8M\xf9b\xf9\xb8\xf9\xdf\xfa\x17\xfb\x97\xfd\xea\xfd\xd2\x00m\x01\xd2\x03\xc6\x04}\x06\xb9\x07>\x08\x94\tk\x08\xa1\tG\x07+\x08\x85\x05\x00\x06\x08\x04)\x04\x8b\x03\x8a\x03\xcd\x03\xff\x03e\x04#\x05\x9f\x052\x07l\x07\xf5\t\n\tw\x0c\xf4\t\x06\x0e=\n\x94\x0e]\n\x97\x0eh\n;\x0e\xc1\t\x0c\r\x83\x08W\x0b\\\x07\xf6\t\xf2\x05\x9f\x08\r\x04\x16\x07r\x02\x02\x06\x10\x01)\x05\xa8\xff#\x04/\xff\xce\x03\xc4\xffA\x04?\x00b\x04d\x00\x0c\x04q\x00\x97\x03V\x00\x05\x03^\x00\xab\x02b\x00`\x02\xf9\xff\xb4\x01\xd6\xffT\x01A\x00\x82\x01j\x00h\x01\x9f\x00S\x01}\x01\xdb\x012\x02&\x02e\x02\xd9\x01\xb2\x02\x91\x01\xf8\x022\x01\xfb\x02\x94\x00\xdc\x02\xf0\xff@\x02\x03\xffJ\x01\xff\xfd\xcd\x00\xb6\xfd\xaf\x00\xfd\xfdz\x00?\xfey\x00\xa3\xfe\xd0\x000\xff\r\x01e\xff\xc4\x00\xdb\xfe\xcf\xff\x82\xfd\x89\xfe\xda\xfbK\xfd_\xfa\xc8\xfb\xde\xf8\xf3\xf9Q\xf7@\xf8%\xf6\x97\xf6)\xf5\xeb\xf47\xf4\x03\xf4\xfb\xf3\x1a\xf4\xa5\xf4\x8b\xf4\x8c\xf5;\xf5\x9c\xf6K\xf6\xff\xf7\xfa\xf6\xf4\xf8\x98\xf6\xcc\xf8\x90\xf5\xe7\xf7!\xf4z\xf6\xe3\xf1\x18\xf4\x85\xefv\xf1\xa8\xeeE\xf09\xef\x8d\xf0\xeb\xef\x15\xf1\xda\xf0\n\xf2\xdc\xf2A\xf4\x99\xf5R\xf7!\xf83\xfa\x87\xf9\xd6\xfb\x17\xf9p\xfbM\xf7q\xf90\xf5\xe8\xf6@\xf3j\xf4>\xf2\xd9\xf2\xcb\xf2\xf5\xf2\t\xf4\xf9\xf3D\xf5=\xf5"\xf7]\xf7\xcb\xf9m\xfa\x95\xfc\xa0\xfd\xf4\xfeH\x00\x11\x00u\x01k\xff\x9c\x00\xfc\xfd\xc6\xfe\xc4\xfc\x11\xfd\xab\xfb\x96\xfb\xbf\xfa\x8a\xfan\xfaz\xfa\xd6\xfa\x84\xfb\xf6\xfb\x8b\xfd\xa7\xfd6\x00S\xff\xb6\x02\x8c\x00o\x04c\x01\\\x05(\x02\xd7\x05\x0c\x035\x06\xa7\x03C\x06p\x03\xa6\x05\xc4\x02\xd9\x04?\x02|\x04\x86\x01"\x04/\x00A\x03\xca\xfeG\x02\x03\xfe\xc9\x01\x14\xfe\xf8\x01\x00\xff\xdc\x02\x18\x00\xcf\x03k\x00\xee\x03^\x00\xa2\x03\xfb\x00\xf9\x03 \x02\xce\x04-\x03\x82\x05,\x04!\x06E\x05\xd7\x06\xa8\x06\xd7\x07\xa3\x08q\t\xe7\nN\x0b\xf8\x0c\xe6\x0c\xe9\x0e>\x0e]\x10\xf2\x0e\xf2\x10\xa4\x0e\x94\x11Q\x0e\xbe\x12\x8c\x0e=\x13B\x0e\x99\x12\x13\r\xd1\x11\x0b\x0c]\x11\xa0\x0b\xfb\x10|\x0b\x89\x10c\x0b\xf5\x0f%\x0bg\x0f\xd1\n(\x0f\xa8\n\x1d\x0f\x93\n\xfc\x0eV\ns\x0e\xb3\t$\r]\x08[\x0b\xac\x06\xae\t4\x05\xee\x07\xc4\x03\xf2\x05)\x02\\\x04\x02\x01\x91\x03\xb3\x00?\x03\xeb\x00?\x03\x86\x01\xf3\x03\xdd\x02q\x05\xf7\x04\xb0\x06\xb3\x06\x8c\x06\xd2\x06K\x05\x8a\x05\xa4\x03\x90\x03y\x01\xdb\x00:\xff\xfd\xfd\n\xfeC\xfc\xe5\xfd\xcd\xfb\x1f\xfe\x05\xfc\xf6\xfe#\xfd\xa1\x00H\xffm\x02\x9c\x01~\x03\x1e\x03}\x03[\x03o\x02H\x02K\x00\xe1\xffM\xfds\xfc\x87\xfa,\xf9\xd5\xf8\x06\xf7\x03\xf8\xe3\xf5\x05\xf8\xc9\xf5\x1e\xf9\xff\xf6\xba\xfa\xe7\xf8w\xfc\x06\xfb\xb7\xfe\x9c\xfd\xeb\x00\xfa\xff\xe0\x01\xd2\x00q\x01\xfc\xff+\x00\x1a\xfe\xa4\xfe\xee\xfbu\xfdE\xfa\x91\xfcA\xf9\x9f\xfb\xa4\xf8\xf6\xfa\xbd\xf8\xfb\xfa\xca\xf9i\xfbM\xfb\xbd\xfb\x8b\xfc\xac\xfb\x12\xfd}\xfb\x1f\xfd\x95\xfb+\xfd\xa3\xfb\x0b\xfdR\xfb\x92\xfc\xdf\xfa\x1c\xfc;\xfa\xa1\xfb+\xf9\xdc\xfa\xe8\xf7\xf2\xf9\xa0\xf6\xf9\xf8\x94\xf5&\xf8?\xf5\xf0\xf7z\xf54\xf8\xf5\xf5\xa8\xf8\xe2\xf6\x80\xf9\xe3\xf7[\xfaZ\xf8\x96\xfa\x99\xf8\x81\xfa\xff\xf8\x7f\xfa|\xf9\x8d\xfa<\xfa\xe7\xfa<\xfb\x97\xfbe\xfc\x88\xfc\xf8\xfd\xf8\xfd\xa4\xff\x87\xff\xd3\x00\x8b\x00\xc0\x011\x01\x8b\x02\x94\x01\x06\x03\x8c\x01\x85\x03}\x01\xce\x03A\x01B\x03M\x00\x84\x02S\xff\x1d\x02\xe4\xfex\x01g\xfe\x9f\x00\xdc\xfd\xfe\xff\xa1\xfdU\xffg\xfd\xed\xfed\xfd\x1c\xff\xe4\xfd:\xff3\xfe&\xff.\xfe]\xffS\xfer\xff9\xfe\xe3\xfek\xfd\xc3\xfd\n\xfc\x05\xfc\x1a\xfa9\xfaA\xf8u\xf9\xa5\xf7\x9e\xf99\xf8\xf9\xf9@\xf9\x90\xfa\xb6\xfa\xae\xfb\xc9\xfc@\xfd>\xff\xb8\xfe_\x01 \xff\x1c\x02!\xfe\x17\x01~\xfc&\xff/\xfbd\xfd\xaf\xfav\xfc\xd1\xfaT\xfcY\xfb\xd4\xfc\xc2\xfco\xfe`\xff`\x01\x91\x02\xe7\x04\xd0\x05_\x08\xbc\x08Q\x0bs\n\xd0\x0c\x9c\n\x87\x0c\xbb\t\x07\x0b5\x08\xc6\x08\x85\x06T\x06S\x05o\x04\xca\x04Y\x03\xf6\x040\x03\xd8\x05\xfb\x03!\x07e\x05\xf0\x08r\x073\x0b\xef\t\xbc\x0c\x86\x0b\x01\r\x95\x0b\xb3\x0c\xcd\n\xdf\x0bV\ta\n=\x07\xee\x08j\x05\xbf\x078\x04\x8e\x06n\x03\xa4\x05<\x03"\x05\x97\x03\xff\x04F\x04n\x05V\x05\xd5\x05\x1f\x06\x8f\x05\x07\x06:\x05\xc4\x05\x0e\x05\xaa\x05w\x045\x05\xf2\x03\xe4\x04\xe9\x03\x17\x05a\x03\xc5\x04\x10\x02\x9c\x03\xe9\x00\x8e\x02=\x00\xf5\x01\xe0\xff\xad\x01\xff\xff\xe5\x01z\x00x\x02\xe1\x00\xe9\x02\x0b\x01\x03\x03"\x01\xea\x02s\x01\xee\x02\xd8\x01\xf7\x02\xb5\x01|\x02E\x01\xc3\x01\x90\x01\xd9\x01\x95\x02\xb9\x02\x8f\x03\x8e\x03\x9b\x04c\x04\xdf\x05S\x05\x90\x06\x8c\x05\x81\x06\xe2\x04\x93\x06@\x04\xe2\x06\xca\x03\xd6\x06\xf7\x02y\x06\xe2\x01\xcf\x05\x9f\x00t\x04\xdb\xfe\x93\x02\xd1\xfc\x88\x00\xe4\xfa'
```

Comment: Try using the [winsound](https://docs.python.org/3/library/winsound.html#module-winsound) module.

Comment: Do I need to install winsound with pip?

Comment: No, it should already be there if you're using Windows.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand [winsound docs](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/winsound.html) correctly, you can play *.wav file following way:

```
import winsound
winsound.PlaySound('D:/Music/Chris Stapleton - Nobody to Blame.wav', winsound.SND_FILENAME)
```

I can not test it so please try it and write if it is working for you.

Comment: winsound doesn't work for me. Nothing happens.